# Invalid Binary after Xcode 8.2 Update

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect

I tried to push an update to my app today after updating to Xcode 8.2 and I am getting an invalid Binary Error. I have never seen this before. The iOS Deployment target for my app is iOS 9.0. Has anyone seen this error or know how to fix it?

This is the contents of the email that explained what was invalid about the binary:

```
Invalid sdk value - The value provided for the sdk portion of LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS in appname.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib is 10.2 which is greater than the maximum allowed value of 10.1.

Invalid sdk value - The value provided for the sdk portion of LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS in appname.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib is 10.2 which is greater than the maximum allowed value of 10.1.

Invalid sdk value - The value provided for the sdk portion of LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS in appname.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib is 10.2 which is greater than the maximum allowed value of 10.1.

Invalid sdk value - The value provided for the sdk portion of LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS in appname.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib is 10.2 which is greater than the maximum allowed value of 10.1.

Invalid sdk value - The value provided for the sdk portion of LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS in appname.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire is 10.2 which is greater than the maximum allowed value of 10.1.
```

Comment: Are you by any chance using beta version of Xcode 8.2?

Comment: @Munahil no I am using the App Store update that came out today

Comment: Oh okay. This can be a Xcode 8.2 bug. This might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956778/xcode-8-compile-with-ios-9-3-base-sdk

Comment: @Munahil it's not a beta version so is it possible that iTunes connect is not recognizing the latest public version of Xcode?

Comment: Having the same issue.

Comment: @HenryWeber it's nice to know I'm not the only one

Comment: @RudyB :  If you have, you can use old version of Xcode i.e 8.1

Comment: No you're definitely not the only one...

Comment: @RudyB Are you using Swift 2.3 or Swift3?

Comment: @d.felber swift 3

Comment: It's okay right now! It seems Apple updated their system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears the problem is wide spread and it is similar to when the 9.2 GM was released. The iTunes Connect backend hasn't quite updated yet, so we will just have to remain patient and keep trying.

It appears the problem is usually resolved within one day of the GM being released.

Edit: 
In the meantime, others have mentioned that you can change the SDK version back to 10.1 and submit your app.

When the problem is resolved, you should not have to resubmit to iTunes connect. You will simply be able to submit the already uploaded binary for review once again.

Update: As of 12/13/16 3:15 PM PST the problem has been fixed. Submit your apps for review again.

Comment: Apple, you HAVE to prevent these damn "incidents" eventually. There have been entirely too many like this the past couple of years.

Comment: I heard this is fixed, incase anyone else is waiting to submit. You can just re-submit the rejected build per this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade your XCode version, then try it. I am sure it will work for you.

Comment: 8.2 is no longer beta. It was released to the App Store today

Comment: This is a good answer for now to go back to Xcode 8.1, but the description above needs to be edited because Xcode 8.2 is no longer a beta version.

Answer (score -1):

my two cents:
I use Xcode 9 and got:

he value provided for the sdk portion of \ LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS in MyApp.app/MyApp is 11.3 which is greater than the maximum allowed value of 11.2.

It was due to a build using Xcode 9.2 beta that leaves its data in DerivedData.
So cleaning DerivedData solves the issue.