# After updating to Xcode 10.2: Invalid Toolchain error when trying to submit app to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, appstore-approval

Xcode automatically updated to version 10.2 today. As well I wanted to submit a new version of my **App Store** today. After submitting I got the following email:

> **App Store Connect**
>   **Dear Developer**,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent submission for your
>   app, "my app". Please correct the following issues, then upload again.
>
> **Invalid Toolchain** - Your app was built with a beta version of `Xcode` or SDK. Apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the
>   GM version of `Xcode 9` and the SDK for `iOS 11`, `tvOS 11`, `watchOS
>   4`, or `macOS 10.13` or later.
>
> Best regards,
>
> **The App Store Team**

Whats the problem? Xcode 10.2 isn't in beta anymore as I never downloaded the beta version. Am I doing something wrong or is this apples fault?

Comment: Probably Apple's fault, as even the direct download link is not yet available.

Comment: You’re not the only one! I have the very same issue uploading a build. Updated Xcode from App Store, not from Apple Developer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favourite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Apple has fixed it!
Pushed “Submit for review” again, without any changes, with the same binary.
And the build stays in `Waiting for Review` status for a few hours already.

Answer (score 2):

Found an entry from Apple Developer Forums that I am not the only one. No solution suggested there except waiting so that I will just wait ...

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/115062

Answer (score 2):

FYI, I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44323009/error-itms-90534-invalid-toolchain) and it doesn't work.

It seems that Apple was bit "careless" previously, by not updating their backend to accept the latest XCode GM version. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113750/invalid-binary-after-xcode-8-2-update) for example.

Unfortunately, it seems to me that the only possible solutions are either waiting for Apple to fix it or [downgrading your XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756026/how-to-downgrade-xcode-to-previous-version) version to 10.1

Answer (score 0):

I think this fixed it for me.

Open the project in Xcode then click on the most top level item in the Project Navigator. Open the right pane and under Project Format switch it from Xcode 9.3-compatible to Xcode 10.0-compatible. Increase the build number by one then upload the app again through Archive and resubmit the new build.