# Problem with uploading app to iTunes connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I updated my XCode to 10.0.2 version today. After update I can not upload new version of my app to iTunes Connect.

> Invalid Toolchain - Your app was built with a beta version of Xcode or
>   SDK. Apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the GM version
>   of Xcode 9 and the SDK for iOS 11, tvOS 11, watchOS 4, or macOS 10.13
>   or later.

Changed Project Format to Xcode 10.0-compatible and got this message again.

Any issues?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After updating to Xcode 10.2: Invalid Toolchain error when trying to submit app to App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55361717/after-updating-to-xcode-10-2-invalid-toolchain-error-when-trying-to-submit-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug on the part of Apple. They already fixed it.