# How to open Xcode 8 project's storyboard into Xcode 7 without any error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

This link is not use full  for me : [The document Main.storyboard requires Xcode 8.0 or later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851459/the-document-main-storyboard-requires-xcode-8-0-or-later)

Comment: It's correct, but after you change, DO NOT open it back in XCode 8 or else it will turn back to XCode 8 format, thats what i got

Comment: I hate Xcode 8 as well. Sad progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do this, but I would be wary about doing so. You can find information here: http://radex.io/xcode7-xcode8/

> Go through all of your .xib and .storyboard files, open the right
>   sidebar, go to the first (File inspector) tab, and find the “Opens in”
>   setting.
>
> It will most likely say “Default (7.0)”. Change it to “Xcode 7.0”.
>   This will ensure that even if you touch the file in Xcode 8, it will
>   only make changes that are backwards-compatible with Xcode 7.

Comment: not working,Each time i got message choose device which changes it to xcode 8.0