# How to call method of another class which uses self in objective C

Tags: ios, iphone, methods, call

RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers class below (Github library to swipe between controllers) it also provides an option where i can tap on buttons(which are names of viewControllers) how ever i am implementing a next button in each of my viewcontroller, so that if a user doesnot know he can swipe he can simply click on next button to go to next controller:

```
   -(void)setupSegmentButtons {
    navigationView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.navigationBar.frame.size.height)];


    NSInteger numControllers = [viewControllerArray count];

    if (!buttonText) {
         buttonText = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: @"Login",@"Personal",@"Contact",@"Club Info",nil]; //%%%buttontitle
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<numControllers; i++) {

        RKButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X_BUFFER+i*(self.view.frame.size.width-2*X_BUFFER)/numControllers-X_OFFSET, Y_BUFFER, (self.view.frame.size.width-2*X_BUFFER)/numControllers, HEIGHT)];

        [navigationView addSubview:RKButton];

        RKButton.tag = i; //%%% IMPORTANT: if you make your own custom buttons, you have to tag them appropriately

        [RKButton setBackgroundColor:ThemeColor];//%%% buttoncolors

        [RKButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tapSegmentButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        //[RKButton addTarget:self action:@selector(CalltapSegmentButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [RKButton setTitle:[buttonText objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //%%%buttontitle

        [_RKSwipeRegisterModal.RKButtonArray addObject:RKButton];

        NSLog(@"_RKSwipeRegisterModal.RKButtonArray %@",_RKSwipeRegisterModal.RKButtonArray);

    }

    pageController.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.titleView = navigationView;


    [self setupSelector];
}
```

and the selector method is below:

```
-(void)tapSegmentButtonAction:(UIButton *)RKButton {

    if (!self.isPageScrollingFlag) {

        NSInteger tempIndex = self.currentPageIndex;

        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

        //%%% check to see if you're going left -> right or right -> left
        if (RKButton.tag > tempIndex) {

            //%%% scroll through all the objects between the two points
            for (int i = (int)tempIndex+1; i<=RKButton.tag; i++) {
                [pageController setViewControllers:@[[viewControllerArray objectAtIndex:i]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:^(BOOL complete){

                    //%%% if the action finishes scrolling (i.e. the user doesn't stop it in the middle),
                    //then it updates the page that it's currently on
                    if (complete) {



                        [weakSelf updateCurrentPageIndex:i];
                    }
                }];
            }
        }

        //%%% this is the same thing but for going right -> left
        else if (RKButton.tag < tempIndex) {
            __weak typeof(self) kjhg = self;
            for (int i = (int)tempIndex-1; i >= RKButton.tag; i--) {
                [pageController setViewControllers:@[[viewControllerArray objectAtIndex:i]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:YES completion:^(BOOL complete){
                    if (complete) {

                        [weakSelf updateCurrentPageIndex:i];
                    }
                }];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now i have created a global array of button created in above method and passed it in below code from another class.

Now i want to call the above method from first class using below code:

```
-(void)callMethodOfSecondClass {

        UIButton *button = [globalArrayOfButtons objectAtIndex:1];

        [rkSwipeControllrObject tapSegmentButtonAction:button];

    }
```

Now the issue is obviously self.currentPageIndex is nil in second class.

How do i give it the value of its original earlier self.

Any help please

Comment: are you presenting or pushing second view controller?

Comment: neither for second class, actually its a third party class library, but i want to call a method of second class.

Comment: @ios_Dev.  your question is not fully understandable.please add some thing more to understand us then we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now the issue is obviously self.currentPageIndex is nil in second
>   class.
>
> How do i give it the value of its original earlier self.

You cannot. `self` always refers to the object that owns the method that's executing. If `self.currentPageIndex` is `nil`, that's because the object that you're sending the message `methodOfSecondClass:` to has `nil` for it's `currentPageIndex` property.

It's hard to see what'g going on in your code because your `-callMethodOfSecondClass:` method doesn't actually ever call `-methodOfSecondClass:` despite your claim to the contrary. Could you make sure you've provided the real code that exhibits the problem?

One possible problem is that you've got a case of mistaken identity. You may have two (or more!) instances of `SecondClass`, where you know the `currentPageIndex` of one is valid, but you're sending the `-methodOfSecondClass :` message to a different instance than the one you expect.

> 'currentPageIndex' is not nil inside second class, it is only nil when
>   it is called from another class. i understand when i 'rkSwipeControllr
>   = [SecondClass new];' it takes new memory, for which 'currentPageIndex' should be 'nil'. But is there any way to assign it
>   the same memory address

When you say `rkSwipeControllr = [SecondClass new]`, `rkSwipeControllr` gets the address of a *new* instance of `SecondClass`, completely separate from any you've created previously.

I think you'll benefit from considering the difference between a class and an instance of that class. The class `SecondClass` defines a *kind* of object, but the class itself doesn't store the information you're interested in, like `currentPageIndex`. To use the class, you have to create an instance of that class, i.e. an object whose *type* is `SecondClass`.

It's like the difference between, say, *Ford F-150*, which is a *kind* of pickup truck, and ***ios_Dev's*** Ford F-150, which is an actual truck (or would be if you drove an F-150). Let's say I go to the dealer and buy a F-150, and I park it in my driveway and put my chainsaw in the back. Later that day, when I need my chainsaw, I have to go to that particular truck to get it. If I instead go to the dealer and buy another F-150, I can't reasonably expect to find my chainsaw in the back, right? And so it is with instances of `SecondClass` -- if you create a new instance of `SecondClass` and set it's `currentPageIndex`, you need to use that *same* object if you want to get that `currentPageIndex` value back. To do that, you need to keep a *strong reference* to the object when you create it. If you don't have at least one strong reference to the object, then *nobody* will remember where the object is, and the Objective-C runtime will helpfully destroy the object. One way to keep that strong reference is in a property marked `strong` in the object that needs to refer to the object later.

Comment: I am not sending current page index, infact i want to use the currentpageIndex of second class.

I am just passing UIbutton in parameter.

How do i go about it ?

Comment: @ios_Dev In Objective-C (and some other languages) "sending a message `bar` to `foo`" means the same as "calling `foo`'s method `bar`". Sorry for any confusion about that, but if you keep at it you'll encounter that lingo often. As I said in the answer, though, if `self.currentPageIndex` is `nil` in `methodOfSecondClass:`, then there's no question that the `self.currentPageIndex ` of the object whose method you're calling has `nil` for the `currentPageIndex`, because `self` refers to exactly that object in the context of one of its methods.

Comment: I'd be happy to suggest a solution (that's why we're here, right?) but I'm still trying to understand the problem. I'll edit the answer above...

Comment: Awesome explanation sir, i know i need chainsaw and i know i need to go to the driveway, but i just dont know how do i go to my driveway..;D

@property (nonatomic, strong) RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers *RKSwipeObject;

Comment: Now Xcode 8 ruins my entire storyboard, have tried everything, last back up was 4 days ago, is there any way around ?

Comment: i have already tried [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851459/the-document-main-storyboard-requires-xcode-8-0-or-later]

Comment: Glad to help. There's not enough information here about your storyboard problem to know what's going on, but the question you cited certainly seems like a good start. If you're still stuck, might want to pose a new question focussed on the storyboard problem.

Comment: i have many questions, is there any way i can ask from you,(as my questions may be silly) because the way you explain things is simply the best. StackOverflow does not provide messaging.