# Main storyboard changed after being required 8.0. Now more than 100 mistakes in the project

Tags: xcode, storyboard, updates

I had the same problem as this on Xcode

[The document Main.storyboard requires Xcode 8.0 or later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851459/the-document-main-storyboard-requires-xcode-8-0-or-later)

Despite that I have never tried to update my Xcode or tried to open any project in an other version of Xcode. I am currently using the beta 7.2

I had done this solution:

As I couldn't open the interface builder. So now I can finally open my storyboard but I have 144 mistakes in my project that I didn't have yesterday.

I updated my question with some of the mistakes I have now on my code. These are the big problem as I don't know how to fix it because it was ok the day before.

So I have for my picker view the following code:

class ABViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

And the error says: Type "ABViewController" does not conform to protocol 'UIPickerViewDataSource'

Any solutions?

Thx