# Visual Studio Mac xamarin ios storybook not working with XCode 12

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I have

Visual Studio 2019 Mac version:  8.7.8 (build 4)

Mac OS Catalina version:  10.15.7

Xamarin Forms : 4.8.0.1560

Xcode 12 : Version 12.1 (12A7403)

I'm trying to add a story board for a launch Screen but its telling be I need Xcode 8 or higher? I have Xcode 12 : Version 12.1 (12A7403) installed on my Mac. I tried to edit the ToolVersion within the Storyboard file to 7.0  with no luck (follow the instruction found here ( [The document Main.storyboard requires Xcode 8.0 or later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851459/the-document-main-storyboard-requires-xcode-8-0-or-later) ). none of the suggestion worked for. if anyone figure this out,  could you share your solution with me :-)

Comment: You could reboot the mac to try again and not adding a new story board for the launch screen to check.

Comment: Did that, Didn't work below is what I did to get around the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is what I did to get it to work:

1: Download Xcode 11.5. ( https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ need to be a apple developer to use this link )

2: Point Visual studio to that SDK (11.5).

3: Restart Visual Studio.

4: Open up the StoryBoard.

5: It worked.

6: Reset the SDK back to 12.1.

7: Restarted Visual studio.

8: Tried to reopen the the StoryBoard it worked.

9: wtf.

it's been working since I did this zombie rain dance.
There is a issue with Xcode 12.1 not sure what it is but its there.